# nginx as a proxy for Websocket to send text messages

Tags: java, nginx, websocket

I have a websocket service running on vm (remote address port 8090). Using Nginx to proxy the connections. nginx config as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
}
```

From my local host I was able to connect to the websocket using ip as `ws://111.11.1.1/websocket`

But, when I send a message from my local host or application to the remote websocket `websocket.sendTextMessage("Message")` I am not able to hit the socket..assuming there is something wrong with my nginx config..

UPDATE: Changed the config for Nginx by adding

`http{ server{..location/{...}}}`

and when I restart Nginx service, i got an error

`nginx emerg http directive is not allowed here in /default.conf:1`

```
nginx: configuration file /nginx.conf test failed
```

Any suggestions are helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following configs, it might help.

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name _;
location / {

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;

    }
```

}